# Можно ли перенести файлы с Яндекс.Диска на VDS?

Tags: vds, яндекс-диск

Есть бекап БД (весит 10 ГБ), лежащий на Яндекс.Диске. Нужно скопировать его на VDS.
Скачать к себе на компьютер а потом залить на VDS по FTP не получается, так как загрузка останавливается на одном гигабайте.
Какие есть варианты копирования?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/

Но если это нужно один раз, то наверное проще конечную ссылку из браузера взять

Comment: Заливайте не по ftp, а по sftp. И вообще, лучше прекращать использовать ftp

Comment: Проблема в том, что получить прямую ссылку нельзя